# Load Map inside of a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I've created navigation drawer and every list item onclick load a fragment. There is home fragment where map will be loaded. I've loaded map in activity extending fragmentactivity but not inside of a fragment. I'm getting error but don't getting it so need suggestion.

//HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnInfoWindowClickListener {

GoogleMap myMap;
private Marker marker;
private Marker marker2;
private Marker marker3;

// GPSTracker class
GpsTracker gps;

// textview
TextView DestinationDistance;

double latitude;
double longitude;

double lat2 = 23.7818442;
double lng2 = 90.3245161;

double lat3 = 23.7818442;
double lng3 = 90.4245161;

private Polyline line;

private ViewGroup userLayout;

// user info views

private TextView txtDistance;
private TextView txtETA;

private int count = 0;
private ArrayList<Polyline>pl;

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    userLayout = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.userLayout);
    txtDistance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtV2);
    txtETA = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtV3);

    myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

    /*Here will be other code to execute asynctask, 
   location detect, add marker etc */

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

*For this code am getting error

```
  'The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type HomeFragment'
```

//fragment_home.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/userLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_infoLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtV1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="#000"
            android:text="Profile Picture" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/position_infoLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtV2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtV3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Send Message" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:-

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

And use:

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

for getting the fragment

Answer (score 0):

try below code, I have did with this way and its working fine.

```
    lnrMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
                addFragment(lnrMap.getId(), mapFragment);
                Timer t = new Timer();
                t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {

                                    googleMap = mapFragment.getExtendedMap();

                                    mapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);
                                    if (googleMap != null) {
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(6));
                                        t.cancel();
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }, 0, 500);

//Just declare one LinearLayout in your xml file with the name of lnrMap, and then above //code will add map in that Linearlayout programatically.

    //Here is sample xml block for lnrMap LinearLayout.

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnrMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

    //addFragment method:

        public void addFragment(int layoutId, Fragment fragment) {
                FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(layoutId, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go here you will find your solution

[The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity for Actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275661/the-method-getsupportfragmentmanager-is-undefined-for-the-type-mainactivity-fo)

Answer (score 0):

First check your Android minimum SDK verson. If it is `below < 11` then use `SupportMapFragment` and if it is `above >11` then use `MapFragment`.

Second just check that have you imported your Fragment as a `android.support.app.v4`